# 4080 vs 3080 TI. Upgade requirements

Tags: gpu

I plan to replace my GPU which is a 3080TI by a 4080 or 4070.

Is there anything which I should be worried about or replacing is a smooth one? (other than wattage).

Interestingly
my used 3080 ti seem to be vauled at least as much  as a new 4070 or more.

Is GPU socket which compatible with
3080 Ti also compatible with 4080?

Sadly my motherboard manual does not  say anything about 4000 series GPUs

Comment: You haven’t provided us any information to determine if your existing system can support the GPU you wish to upgrade to.

Comment: Interestingly I have two motherboards that have had BIOS updates to "Improve compatibility with RTX 40 series GPU" - so that may be something you need to look in to

Comment: A 4070 is weaker than a 3080-Ti, so if you really think you need to upgrade, go for a 4070-Ti (+20% perf) or 4080 (+42% perf from userbenchmark). But it's certainly worth actually considering if this update is really worth it.

Comment: Your used 3080Ti is valued at least as much as a new 4070 or more because it's better card or at least the same. Are you sure this upgrade is actually worth doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PCIe slots haven't changed *that* much in the past few years. They are backward compatible, and very rarely did you saturate the bandwidth of the slot. Any decently modern system (especially one where the 3080TI was a contemporary card to the rest of the build) should be fine.

However the 4000 series nvidia cards use a new style power adaptor known as a [12vhpwr](https://www.overclockers.co.uk/blog/12vhpwr-what-is-it-and-why-do-you-need-it/) that's different from the old PCIe 12v connector. For extra 'fun' - there's reports some of these adaptors burn out if installed incorrectly - and the solution for this is yet [another 'new' connector type that's backwards compatible](https://www.tomshardware.com/news/16-pin-power-connector-gets-a-much-needed-revision-meet-the-new-12v-2x6-connector). In either case you'd need a new power supply or suitable adaptor

Considering all the 'problems' with the power, I'd strongly suggest doing your research before upgrading, or putting off the upgrade till you can get the 'new' style power connector.

Comment: The new connectors melt when not plugged all the way in, however, they have a purposeful issue in that 600 Watts are passed through the pins. The revised 12v connector, which only increases the indentation of the pin, is just a modification of the existing 12v connector. The bigger issue is that without a power supply with a real 12V cable it won’t negotiate with the sense pins. The hardware will still work just not the same.

Comment: Thanks for the information  and warning. For now I will keep my card

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind: The physical dimensions of newer cards are different. 4xxx series cards are a lot bigger. They may not fit your computer case.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the 3080 TI is more powerful than the 4070 by about 5% so unless your goal is power efficiency then ignore the 4070.

The 4080 however is considerably more powerful than the 3080 TI.

The 4080 recommends an 850W PSU; the 3080 TI has the same requirement so there should be zero issues swapping out your GPU assuming you've considered the dimensions of the new 4080 in your computer case.

As for the 12vhpwr connector you can get an adapter like this:

[image]

You should also strongly consider [Cablemod's 12vhpwr right-angle adapter](https://store.cablemod.com/12vhpwr-angled-adapter/) to make sure everything fits nice and snug.

---

> Sadly my motherboard manual does not say anything about 4000 series GPUs

I'd be amazed to see any motherboard manual mention anything about any model-specific GPU.

Comment: Fantastic info. Thanks! So let's say I buy a 4080 and get the above cable(my PSU is fine and my case is big enough), just attach this cable to PSU to feed GPU?

Comment: You will likely be fine. Check your PSU for adequate cables to use that adapter.